# How do I pass value from dropdown in form1 to multiple different forms / multiple different flask handles without using FLASK_WTF

Tags: flask

I have 2 forms **Form1 and Form2 on same Flask html page.How do I pass selected value of dropdown on Form1 to the Flask handle of Form2**

**Form1**

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="environ" name="environ" action="{{url_for('apiOps.getBusiness')}}" method="POST" align="center">
  <div class="input-container">
    <select name="Env" id="Environment">
      <option name="sel" value="sel">Environment</option>
      <option name="dev" value="dev">DEV</option>
      <option name="sit" value="sit">SIT</option>
      <option name="qa" value="qa">QA</option>
      <option name="uat" value="uat">UAT</option>
      <option name="prod" value="west">PROD</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</form>
<script>$(document).ready(function() { $('#Environment').on('change', function() {
                  document.forms.environ.submit();
                  });
                });</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Form1 Flask Handle**

**Note: Below handle is not having Server details (intentionally removed them by placing a variable called Server. Please assume we have some value for it)**

```
`@apiOps.route('/akanaOps#getBusiness', methods=['GET','POST'])
def getBusiness():
    if request.method in ('GET'):
        return render_template('Ops.html')
    else:
        sess=requests.Session()
        Env = str(request.form.get('Env'))
        cook = akanaLogin(Env)
        business_url = protocol + Env + Server + "/api/businesses"
        businessList = sess.get(business_url, headers = {'Accept': '*/*'}, cookies=cook, verify = False)
        bList = json.loads(businessList.text)
        return render_template('Ops.html',BData=bList)`
```

**Now displaying the BData into Form2 on same html page**

```html
<form id="Orgs" name="Orgs" action="{{url_for('apiOps.getAPI')}}"  method="POST" align="center">
<div class="input-container">
<select name="Org" id="Org">
       <option name="sel2" value="sel2">Organization</option>
        {% for z in range(BData['Business']|count) %}
       <option name="{{BData['Business'][z]['BusinessID']}}" value="{{BData['Business'][z]['BusinessID']}}"><b>{{BData['Business'][z]['Name']}}</b></option>
        {% endfor %}</select>
                </div>
            </form>
            <script>$(document).ready(function myFunction() {   $('#Org').on('change', function() {
                  document.forms.Orgs.submit();
                  });
                });</script>
```

**Form2 Flask Handle**

**Note: Below handle is not having Server details (intentionally removed them by placing a variable called Server. Please assume we have some value for it)**

```
`@apiOps.route('/akanaOps#getAPI', methods=['GET','POST'])
def getAPI():
    if request.method in ('GET'):
        return render_template('Ops.html')
    else:
        sess=requests.Session()
        Org = str(request.form.get('Org'))
        apis_url = protocol+Env+ Server +"/api/apis?state=com.soa.api.state.active&BusinessID="+ Org
        api = sess.get(apis_url, headers = {'Accept': 'application/json'}, verify = False)
        api_json = json.loads(api.text)
        return render_template('Ops.html',ApiData=api_json)`
```

**So How do I get Env variable from Form1 to the Flask Handle of Form2?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been resolved by using a session variable to load the environment data from Form1. whenever required I can call the session variable in any route.
Thanks much [@tachyondecay](https://twitter.com/tachyondecay) for support on this issue